# ubuntu - Why modifications to init.d script are ignored

Tags: ubuntu, services, init.d

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04. After I make modification to `/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server` and type:

```
# sudo service gearman-job-server restart
```

it ignores modification I've made. But then I type:

```
# /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server restart
```

everything works. Do those scripts are now in Ubuntu 14.04 are cached somethere?

Comment: Does the service have an `upstart` job file in addition to the sysv init script?

Answer (score 4):

After having a similar problem on Ubuntu 15.10 trying to change the listen address, I discovered that the traditional init scripts are ignored, and the systemd configuration is hard-coded to listen only on 127.0.0.1.

The solution is to modify the systemd configuration, reload it, and then restart the service.

## Modify the configuration

The configuration can be modified directly or via an override file.

### Via direct modification

The systemd service configuration is located at `/lib/systemd/system/gearman-job-server.service`.  Edit this file and change the ExecStart line to include the parameters you need.

### Via an [override file](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Override_Files)

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/gearman-job-server.service.d/gearman-job-server.conf`.

Put the following configuration into the file to override the ExecStart command.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gearmand --pid-file=/run/gearman/server.pid --log-file=/var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log
```

The empty `ExecStart=` line is necessary to remove the original command line.  Without it the system would try and execute both the original and the custom one.

## Reload the configuration

Run the following command so that systemd will reload the service configuration

```
/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
```

## Restart the service

```
service gearman-job-server restart
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `sudo service` Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 will first to look init script in `/etc/init` (upstart) and then `/etc/init.d`, so it first will find this script:

```
/etc/init/gearman-job-server.conf
```

and then

```
/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server
```

Btw there is also bug in gearman-job-server.conf which is described [here](http://jeremykendall.net/2014/09/04/ubuntu-14-dot-04-gearman-config-bug/).